# Is there a way to create and read cookies in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, cookies, flutter-web

I am wondering if there is any way to create and read cookies in Flutter, similar to `document.cookie` in Javascript. It seems logical since Flutter Web becomes Javascript when built.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this

`import 'dart:html';`

`final cookie=document.cookie;`

this will return string like `"key=value; key2=value"`
if you need the data as Map , you should use split and map method to extract the key:value form it

like:

```
import 'dart:html';

final cookie = document.cookie!;
final entity = cookie.split("; ").map((item) {
  final split = item.split("=");
  return MapEntry(split[0], split[1]);
});
final cookieMap = Map.fromEntries(entity);
```

for setting a cookie

```
document.cookie="key=value";
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the cookie only for the current path? Lets say my application is under /flutter/gui, and the cookies shall only be sent to the server if a website makes requests drom this location?

Comment: Or, can we produce cookies that were not sent to the server at all?

Comment: dart:html cant be used by flutter. How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one thing to the above answer

if dart:html gives error with flutter web

use [this Dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html)

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion) also, please show how to use it to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: @starball sometimes if you're using firebase packages, url_launcher, or google maps, dart:html becomes incompatible with dart:js sometimes
so better to add the above package, and import the package when code ask to import dart:html, simple!